# URL modification: Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, url

I have a function that I use to cycle through some pictures which changes my URL. I get my firs URL using angular routes, the "domain" parameter is an array which is made up of the domain.id and the domain.category 
    `<a [routerLink] = "['/image', image.id, domain]">`

When I choose the first image I get the correct structure for my URL. 
    `http://localhost:4200/image/1;id=1;category=testing.`

However when I call my "next" function to cycle through the images I get this URL. 
    `"http://localhost:4200/image/2?id=1&category=testing.`

Basically what I'm asking is it possible to replace the "?" and the "&" and turn them into ";".

```js
next() {
  const next = this.activeId + 1 >= 9 ? 1 : this.activeId + 1;
  const extras: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParams: {
      id: this.domain.id,
      category: this.domain.catergory
    }
  };
  this.router.navigate(['/image/' + next], extras);
}
```

Comment: When you use the HttpClient `queryParams` property, it correctly builds the _search part_ of the URL. Your first example is not compliant with the way Angular works. Need to conform or write your URL parser.

Comment: My first example uses routes So this how i get the first example.   <a [routerLink] = "['/image', image.id, domain]">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string interpolation, try this

use navigateByUrl

```
next() {
    const next = this.activeId + 1 >= 9  ? 1 : this.activeId + 1;
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/image/' + `${next};id=${this.domain.id};category=${this.domain.catergory}`);
}
```

Comment: When I do that the url comes out like that `http://localhost:4200/image/2%3Bid%3D1%3Btesting`

Comment: I tried it like this because you forgot to add the category and for some reason it's not the right syntax? this.router.navigateByUrl('/image/' +`${next};id=${this.domain.id};category=${this.domain.catergory}`);

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot the category

Comment: OK thanks, but now it just comments out everything below it. lol I'm so confused

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use queryParams (which I recommend), you can change your first example that is built with [routerLink]. For example if you:

**Change**

```
<a [routerLink] = "['/image', image.id, domain]">
```

**To**

```
<a [routerLink] = "['/image']" [queryParams]="{imageId: image.id, domain: domain.id, category:domain.category}">
```

Then your first URL will contain "http://localhost:4200/image/1?id=1"

The behavior will be much more consistent throughout your app.

Comment: But I still need that domain array, so I would just just remove it completely?

Comment: No, I wasn't sure what that was, because it doesn't show up in your URL. What is the domain array and how is that related to `category=testing` which wasn't in your comment above.

Comment: @JZG - there you go